# How to draw ellipse's arc on android?

Tags: android, canvas, shapes

I want to draw an arc of ellipse in my android app.
I used this code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        angle=45; //angle of ellipse major axis with X-axis.
        startAngle=0; //start angle of arc
        sweepAngle=90; //sweep angle of arc
        a = 200; //major axis of ellipse
        b = 100; //minor axis of ellipse
        
        canvas.rotate(angle, center.x, center.y);
        //draw the arc
        canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle - angle, sweepAngle, true, paintLine);

        paintLine.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 5, 5 }, 0));
        canvas.drawOval(rect, paintLine);

        canvas.restore();
        paintLine.setPathEffect(null);
    }
```

I receive this shape:

[image]

The arc I need should start and end at the red point at this image:
[image]

Please tell me what mistake did I make.

Thanks.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, yu have to set angle to 90 instead of 45. A circle consists of 360 degrees, a quarter is 90 degrees. If You want to draw 90 degrees, the angle have to be even 90. Setting startAngle to 0 means, drawing start at 3 o clock. If you want to start your drawing at 6 o clok, you have to set 0 - 90. so startAngle=0; angle=90; If I get right, I will set it as answer

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, The `angle` is an angle of ellipse with X-axis. If I set angle = 90, the major axis of ellipse will be drawn at verticle, and then the Arc will have another appearance.

Comment: ok, than set new values for the startAngle in drawArc method. For example float startValue = -90; Only for testing if I am right....

Comment: When I set -90 for `drawArc` method, The starting point will above red line. Note that this issue just occur with ellipse shape, Every thing is ok with Circle.

Comment: For anyone who happens upon this thread... Please never use this line in your `onDraw` method `paintLine.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 5, 5 }, 0));` You're better off to create 2 paint objects.

Answer (score 1):

When android draws an elliptic arc, it is as if it does so by first drawing a circular arc over the supplied sweep angle. Then it scales this circular arc so that it fits the specified ellipse. The the start and sweep-angles of the ellipse will be different from the start and sweep-angles specified. To get a wanted-angle, one must specify an actual-angle as tan(actual-angle) = (a/b)*tan(wanted-angle)

```
public class Main3Activity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    View view = new View(this) {
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.save();
            float angle=45; //angle of ellipse major axis with X-axis.
            // These are the wanted angles
            float startAngle_ = (float)Math.toRadians(315); //start angle of arc
            float endAngle_ = (float)Math.toRadians(45); //end angle of arc
            float a = 200; //major axis of ellipse
            float b = 100; //minor axis of ellipse
            float xc = getWidth()/2f;
            float yc = getHeight()/2f;

            // These are the angles to use
            float startAngle = (float)Math.toDegrees(
                            Math.atan2(a*Math.sin(startAngle_),b*Math.cos(startAngle_)));
            float endAngle = (float)Math.toDegrees(
                    Math.atan2(a*Math.sin(endAngle_),b*Math.cos(endAngle_)));
            float sweepAngle = endAngle - startAngle;

            RectF rect = new RectF(xc-a,yc-b,xc+a,yc+b);
            Paint paintLine = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paintLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            canvas.rotate(angle,xc,yc);
            //draw the arc
            canvas.drawArc(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, true, paintLine);

            paintLine.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 5, 5 }, 0));
            canvas.drawOval(rect, paintLine);

            canvas.restore();
            paintLine.setPathEffect(null);
        }
    };

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    addContentView(view,layout);
}
```

This question is nearly seven years old! About time to update the documentation?